# Validation messages displayed on "blur" but not on submit

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a formgroup which contains 3 formgroups. Each of these formgroups have formControls inputs. When i type something in one input, which does not meet the validations, and then go to the other input, it works, the message is displayed apropriately. But when i click on the submit button, it doesn't work. Then main formgroup is invalid but still doesn't display any message.
Anyone has an idea ?

**main formgroup**

---

```
    <form (ngSubmit)="saveBaseInfos()"
          [formGroup]="baseInfosForm">
    ***//first child formgroup***
      <address [title]="'base-infos.address-to-be-insured.title' | translate"
                    name="addressToBeInsured"
                    [group]="baseInfosForm.controls['insuredAddress']">
      </address>
    ***//second child formgroup***
      <about-you [group]="baseInfosForm.controls['aboutYou']">
      </about-you>
    ***//third child formgroup***
      <address *ngIf="boolDisplayForm==false"
                    [title]="'base-infos.current-address.title' | translate"
                    name="currentAddress"
                    [group]="baseInfosForm.controls['currentAddress']">
      </address>

      <button type="submit"
              class="bigBtn"
              [innerHTML]="'base-infos.buttons.submit' | translate">
      </button>
    </form>

                    **********
```

**main form ts file**

```
  this.baseInfosForm = this._fb.group({
      aboutYou: this._fb.group({}),
      insuredAddress: this._fb.group({}),
      currentAddress: this._fb.group({})
    });
    ***/* the submit function */***
    if (this.baseInfosForm.valid) {
        this._router.navigate(['');
   }
```

---

**adress component ts file**

```
   this.addressForm
          .addControl('postalCode',
            new FormControl('',
              { updateOn: 'blur',
                validators: validations.PostalCodeValidation
              }));
     this.addressForm
            .addControl('sameAddress',
            new FormControl('',
              { updateOn: 'blur',
                validators: validations.SameAddressValidation
              }));

          **********
```

**html of the address component**

```
     <div class="divSection">
      <form id="addressFormId"
            [formGroup]="addressForm">
        <h2 [innerHTML]="title"></h2>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="{{name}}-postalCode"
                 [innerHTML]="'address.fields.postal-code.label' | translate"></label>
          <input id="{{name}}-postalCode"
                 formControlName="postalCode"
                 type="text"
                 [placeholder]="'address.fields.postal-code.placeholder' | translate"
                 [textMask]="{mask: maskPattern.postalCodeMask}"
                 [value]="states['postalCode']"/>
          <sosi-error-message [messages]="validationErrorMessages.postalCode"></sosi-error-message>
        </div>

      <radios 
             required
             [parentFormGroup]="addressForm">
      </radios>
     ...
```

---

**and radio component ts file**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'radios',
  templateUrl: './radios.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./radios.component.scss']
})
export class RadiosComponent  implements OnInit {
@Input() parentFormGroup: FormGroup;
```

---

**radio html formcontrol**

```
<div  [formGroup]="parentFormGroup"
     [id]="name"
     [ngClass]="getFlexClass()">
  <div class="mega-radio-container"
       *ngFor="let curItem of items; let i = index; let last = last"
       [style.width]="getWidthOfOne(i)"
       [style.flex-grow]="getFlexGrow()">
    <input required [formControlName]="sameAddress"
           type="radio"
           [disabled]="disabled"
           [value]="curItem.value"
           [checked]="value!=null && curItem.key == value"
           (click)="onClickItem(curItem.key)"/>
    <label class="mega-radio"
           for="{{name}}-{{i}}"
           tabindex="1">
      {{ (curItem.value | translate) == null ? curItem.value : (curItem.value | translate) }}
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

**/* in this html i pass a list to display them as radio buttons  */**

I think the problem of validation messages comes from the fact that the radio child component is a formcontrol itself, and is not binded to its parent formgroup... something like that problably because here is what i get inside the console:
**RadiosComponent.html:8 ERROR Error: Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute**

regards
youssef

Comment: It would be great if you added some code to your question

Comment: The code displaying the error messages must be wrong. But you didn't post any single line of code. So how could we help?

Comment: you're right, below the code

Comment: Post your code in the question. Not as an answer. And post the **relevant** code, i.e. the code displaying the validation error message, and deciding when to display them.

Comment: added the code inside the question. thanks